# apache tomcat start fails with phoenix-5.0.0-HBase-2.0-client.jar in project lib folder

Tags: java, hadoop, tomcat, hbase, apache-phoenix

i have a web application which connects to apache phoenix; therefore i added phoenix-5.0.0-HBase-2.0-client.jar to dependencies and it works perfectly in intellij on local but when i start tomcat in server i get this error message:

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1125)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1859)
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.Utils.store(Lorg/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig;Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)V
                at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer.addServletWithExistingRegistration(JerseyServletContainerInitializer.java:310)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer.onStartupImpl(JerseyServletContainerInitializer.java:170)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(JerseyServletContainerInitializer.java:143)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
                ... 10 more
07-Feb-2021 09:10:32.298 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Error deploying web application directory 
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:747)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1125)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1859)
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
```

and it gets resolved when i remove phoenix-5.0.0-HBase-2.0-client.jar from projects lib folder!
servers operating system is centos. i dont use spring boot, gradle or maven.

Comment: It seems you have mismatched version of Jersey. Did you download the jar from [Phoenix Website](https://phoenix.apache.org/download.html)? That distribution contains the fattest jar I've ever seen (135 MiB) with many dependencies embedded. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66085846/edit) your question and add the list of the other libraries in `WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz tnx u for your answer; i added other jar files to lib and i still get the same error message.

Comment: You misunderstood my comment: `phoenix-5.0.0-HBase-2.0-client.jar` contains many other jars (hence it is a **fat jar**). Please add to the question which other jars you have in `WEB-INF/lib`, so we can point you to which ones conflict with `phoenix-5.0.0-HBase-2.0-client.jar`.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz yes i misunderstood your comment. i added the file names to the question; unfortunately it's a long list!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to dependency hell! The jar file `phoenix-5.0.0-HBase-2.0-client.jar` contains the equivalent of 170 jar files (listed below as Maven `groupId:artifactId:version`). Specifically it contains Jersey 1.19, while you have already Jersey 2.15. Whenever you have multiple version of the same library on your classpath you will get **linkage** errors as the one in your question. One Jersey library (probably 2.15) tried to load a dependency, but the dependency came from another version (probably 1.19).

The solution is **not to use** fat jars like `phoenix-5.0.0-HBase-2.0-client.jar`, but use Maven or another system to deal with dependencies. They might still get it wrong (e.g. the [com.sun.xml.bind](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-core/3.0.0) and [org.glassfish.jaxb](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-core/3.0.0)'s version of `jaxb-core` contain the same classes, but Maven does not know that), but the result is much better, than manual dependency management.

In your case, if you just need the `org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver` you need to include the [phoenix-core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.phoenix/phoenix-core/5.0.0-HBase-2.0) artifact and let Maven do the rest.

You'll end up with many useless dependencies (e.g. you can immediately exclude the `jetty-*` dependencies, since those are the libraries of the Jetty Servlet container, as well as `hbase-server` if you are connecting to an external one), but hopefully there will be no conflicts.

```
com.clearspring.analytics:stream:2.9.5
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.0
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.0
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.0
com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:2.7.8
com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:2.7.8
com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:2.7.8
com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:5.0.3
com.github.stephenc.findbugs:findbugs-annotations:1.3.9-1
com.github.stephenc.jcip:jcip-annotations:1.0-1
com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1
com.google.guava:guava:13.0.1
com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.3.0
com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.5.0
com.google.re2j:re2j:1.1
com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.54
com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:4.41.1
com.salesforce.i18n:i18n-util:1.0.4
com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0
com.squareup.okio:okio:1.4.0
com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-guice:1.19
com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:1.19
com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.19
com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:1.19
com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:1.19
com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:1.19
com.tdunning:json:1.8
com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:2.3
commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.3
commons-cli:commons-cli:1.4
commons-codec:commons-codec:1.7
commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.2
commons-daemon:commons-daemon:1.0.13
commons-io:commons-io:2.5
commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6
commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
commons-net:commons-net:3.1
io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:3.1.0
io.netty:netty-all:4.1.17.Final
io.netty:netty:3.10.5.Final
javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2
javax.servlet.jsp:javax.servlet.jsp-api:2.3.1
javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0
javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final
javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1
javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:1.1.1
javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.11
jline:jline:2.11
log4j:log4j:1.2.17
net.minidev:accessors-smart:1.1
net.minidev:json-smart:2.2.1
org.antlr:antlr-runtime:3.5.2
org.apache.avro:avro-ipc:1.7.3
org.apache.avro:avro:1.7.7
org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.1
org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.4.1
org.apache.commons:commons-configuration2:2.1.1
org.apache.commons:commons-crypto:1.0.0
org.apache.commons:commons-csv:1.0
org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6
org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1
org.apache.curator:curator-client:2.12.0
org.apache.curator:curator-framework:2.12.0
org.apache.curator:curator-recipes:2.12.0
org.apache.flume:flume-ng-configuration:1.4.0
org.apache.flume:flume-ng-core:1.4.0
org.apache.flume:flume-ng-sdk:1.4.0
org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-annotations:3.0.0
org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:3.0.0
org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:3.0.0
org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:3.0.0
org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-distcp:2.7.4
org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-hdfs-client:3.0.0
org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-hdfs:3.0.0
org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-common:3.0.0
org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-core:3.0.0
org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient:3.0.0
org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-api:3.0.0
org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-common:3.0.0
org.apache.hbase.thirdparty:hbase-shaded-miscellaneous:2.1.0
org.apache.hbase.thirdparty:hbase-shaded-netty:2.1.0
org.apache.hbase.thirdparty:hbase-shaded-protobuf:2.1.0
org.apache.hbase:hbase-annotations:2.0.0
org.apache.hbase:hbase-client:2.0.0
org.apache.hbase:hbase-common:2.0.0
org.apache.hbase:hbase-hadoop-compat:2.0.0
org.apache.hbase:hbase-hadoop2-compat:2.0.0
org.apache.hbase:hbase-http:2.0.0
org.apache.hbase:hbase-mapreduce:2.0.0
org.apache.hbase:hbase-metrics-api:2.0.0
org.apache.hbase:hbase-metrics:2.0.0
org.apache.hbase:hbase-procedure:2.0.0
org.apache.hbase:hbase-protocol-shaded:2.0.0
org.apache.hbase:hbase-protocol:2.0.0
org.apache.hbase:hbase-replication:2.0.0
org.apache.hbase:hbase-server:2.0.0
org.apache.hbase:hbase-zookeeper:2.0.0
org.apache.htrace:htrace-core4:4.2.0-incubating
org.apache.htrace:htrace-core:3.1.0-incubating
org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1
org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.0.1
org.apache.kerby:kerb-admin:1.0.1
org.apache.kerby:kerb-client:1.0.1
org.apache.kerby:kerb-common:1.0.1
org.apache.kerby:kerb-core:1.0.1
org.apache.kerby:kerb-crypto:1.0.1
org.apache.kerby:kerb-identity:1.0.1
org.apache.kerby:kerb-server:1.0.1
org.apache.kerby:kerb-simplekdc:1.0.1
org.apache.kerby:kerb-util:1.0.1
org.apache.kerby:kerby-asn1:1.0.1
org.apache.kerby:kerby-config:1.0.1
org.apache.kerby:kerby-pkix:1.0.1
org.apache.kerby:kerby-util:1.0.1
org.apache.kerby:kerby-xdr:1.0.1
org.apache.kerby:token-provider:1.0.1
org.apache.mina:mina-core:2.0.4
org.apache.phoenix:phoenix-core:5.0.0-HBase-2.0
org.apache.phoenix:phoenix-flume:5.0.0-HBase-2.0
org.apache.phoenix:phoenix-pig:5.0.0-HBase-2.0
org.apache.phoenix:phoenix-spark:5.0.0-HBase-2.0
org.apache.tephra:tephra-api:0.14.0-incubating
org.apache.tephra:tephra-core:0.14.0-incubating
org.apache.tephra:tephra-hbase-compat-2.0:0.14.0-incubating
org.apache.twill:twill-api:0.8.0
org.apache.twill:twill-common:0.8.0
org.apache.twill:twill-core:0.8.0
org.apache.twill:twill-discovery-api:0.8.0
org.apache.twill:twill-discovery-core:0.8.0
org.apache.twill:twill-zookeeper:0.8.0
org.apache.yetus:audience-annotations:0.5.0
org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:1.3.8
org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:3.1.4
org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:9.3.19.v20170502
org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:9.3.19.v20170502
org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:9.3.19.v20170502
org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:9.3.19.v20170502
org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:9.3.19.v20170502
org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util-ajax:9.3.19.v20170502
org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:9.3.19.v20170502
org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:9.3.19.v20170502
org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:9.3.19.v20170502
org.fusesource.leveldbjni:leveldbjni-all:1.8
org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:2.5.0-b32
org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:2.5.0-b32
org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:2.5.0-b32
org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:2.5.0-b32
org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:2.5.0-b32
org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:1.0.1
org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:2.25.1
org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:2.25.1
org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.25.1
org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:2.25.1
org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:2.25.1
org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-jaxb:2.25.1
org.glassfish.web:javax.servlet.jsp:2.3.2
org.glassfish:javax.el:3.0.1-b11-SNAPSHOT
org.iq80.snappy:snappy:0.3
org.jamon:jamon-runtime:2.4.1
org.javassist:javassist:3.20.0-GA
org.jruby.jcodings:jcodings:1.0.18
org.jruby.joni:joni:2.1.2
org.jvnet:tiger-types:1.4
org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:6.1.26
org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:6.1.26
org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api:2.5-20110124
org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.4
org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.25
org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:1.0.5
sqlline:sqlline:1.2.0
```