# Java & Gradle & log4j NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, log4j, log4j2

I'm trying to use log4j in my java core console application. In the documentation there is sample code on how to add Gradle dependency for log4j:

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/maven-artifacts.html

```
dependencies {
  compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.14.1'
  compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.14.1'
}
```

I pasted it to my `build.gradle` file and wrote sample code for running the code.

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class Program {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("HelloWorld");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.error("Just a test error entry");
    }
}
```

along with that I also added manifest in order to run the code from the console.

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "Program"
    }
}
```

If I build it with Gradle - everything is built successfully. But if I try to run java -jar  from my build directory then I got

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager
        at Program.<clinit>(Program.java:5)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
        ... 1 more
```

I found 1 workaround: modify to jar{} section:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "Program"
    }

    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

and it started working, I even try to zip .jar file and saw that there is log4j dependency added.

But what is I don't want transitive dependency on log4j? If I set `implementation group` instead of `compile group` it doesn't work again. Is there any complete example of using log4j?

On top of that, one thing to point, while it is not working with java -jar <.jar>, for some reason it still works in Intellij idea. Could someone explain me why?

Comment: If a JAR file requires external dependencies you need to use the `-cp` argument to the `java` executable (or the `CLASSPATH` environment variable). Alternatively some implementations of Java can add additional JARs to the classpath by reading the manifest (cf. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22659463/11748454))

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz, could you please share any documentation about this? I've read gradle docs, but didn't find that we should specify classpath, etc for using `implementation`

Comment: see [What is a classpath and how do I set it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2396493/11748454) When Intellij runs a project, it does something similar to setting a classpath.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz, sorry, I cannot find any documentation in Gradle about it. I saw the link, but what classpath should I tell my `build.gradle`? Because in my built .jar there are no log4j jars if I put `implementation`. Only if I put `compile`. I've read that the difference between them in transitive dependencies, but probably there is something else. And the thing which upsets me - is there is no documentation about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are encountering is caused by a problem in the application's classpath, when you launch the application (cf. [What is a classpath and how do I set it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2396493/11748454)).

Gradle has many options to help you with setting the classpath right. Since you don't mention any Gradle version, I'll use version 7.1 in the examples. Assume you have this `build.gradle` file in a project named `appName`:

```groovy
plugins {
  id 'application'
}

dependencies {
  implementation group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api',  version: '2.14.1'
  runtimeOnly    group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.14.1'
}

application {
  mainClass = 'com.example.App'
}
```

(`log4j-core` is not necessary to compile your code, so it is in the `runtimeOnly` dependency configuration, cf. [dependency configurations](https://docs.gradle.org/7.1/userguide/java_plugin.html#tab:configurations))

#### Manually setting the classpath

If you generate a plain JAR file (execute the [`jar` task](https://docs.gradle.org/7.1/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_tasks) and look in `build/libs`) you can execute the application with:

```
java -cp log4j-api-2.14.1.jar:log4j-core-2.14.1.jar:appName.jar com.example.App
```

(I assume all jars are in the current directory; the path separator is system specific, on Windows it is `;`)

This becomes easily difficult to get right, therefore the `application` Gradle plugin generates a shell and a batch script to help you: execute the [`installDist` task](https://docs.gradle.org/7.1/userguide/application_plugin.html#sec:application_tasks) and look into `build/install/appName` (or you can use the `distZip` or `distTar` tasks for a compressed version of this folder). Setting up the correct command is reduced to calling:

```
bin/appName
```

#### Hardcoding the classpath in the Manifest

You can also hardcode the dependencies needed in the JARs manifest file. In Gradle you can do it with:

```groovy
jar {
  manifest {
    attributes(
      'Main-Class': 'com.example.App',
      'Class-Path': configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.name }.join(' ')
    )
  }
}
```

to obtain a manifest file with all the information needed to start the application:

```
Main-Class: pl.copernik.gradle.App
Class-Path: log4j-core-2.14.1.jar log4j-api-2.14.1.jar
```

Notice the usage of `runtimeClasspath`, which is a configuration that contains both the `runtimeOnly` and `implementation` dependency configurations needed to start the application.

If the dependency jars are in the same folder as `appName.jar`, you can run the application with:

```
java -jar appName.jar
```

#### Spring Boot loader

If you want to have all dependencies in a single JAR, you can use the [Spring Boot Gradle plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/) instead of the `application` plugin:

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.3'
}
```

The [`bootJar`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging-executable) task will produce an `appName.jar` resembling in its structure the `appName.zip` file produced by the `distZip` file. However the shell/batch scripts are replaced with Java code, so you can call:

```
java -jar appName.jar
```

#### Fat Jar

What you did in your question with:

```groovy
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "com.example.App"
    }
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

is usually called **fat JAR**. Basically it is produced by unzipping your jar file and all dependencies into a single folder and zipping it back together.

This works, but has some disadvantages: e.g. you might lose licence information on the dependencies (which might be a licence violation) and you will not be able to replace the dependencies with new versions without recompiling. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66088981/11748454) for an example of an absurdly large fat jar.